# Appending columns at begining of csv file

Tags: powershell

Using this code, I am writing first couple of columns to a csv

```
$Hash = [ordered]@{}

foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
    $Hash[$Property] = (($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$NumberOfRowsToPick
}

[pscustomobject]$Hash | Export-Csv "C:\script\sum_$Server$Services.csv" -NoType -Force
```

which returns this result:

```
rx_AVERAGE  rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN  
20538.44384 73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994
```

After that I am appending 3 columns using this code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "c:\script\sum_$Server$Services.csv"                 

foreach($row in $csv)
{                    
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value $Server -Force
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Start Time" -Value $FirstTimeStamp -Force 
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "End Time" -Value $LastTimeStamp -Force
}

$csv | Export-Csv -Path "c:\script\sum_$Server$Services.csv" -NoType
```

which is producing a final result:

```
rx_AVERAGE  rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN  ServerName  Start Time  End Time
20538.44384 73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994 devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000
```

Newly added columns are getting added at the end.

I need to add the newly added columns at the beginning, like so:

```
ServerName  Start Time  End Time rx_AVERAGE rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000 20538.44384  73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994

ServerName  Start Time  End Time rx_AVERAGE rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000 20538.44384  73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994
```

Please let me know how can I add them at the beginning instead of end?

Comment: Add them _before_ adding the remaining properties then: - `$Hash = [ordered]@{ServerName=$Server;"Start Time"=$FirstTimeStamp;"End Time" -Value $LastTimeStamp}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the properties into the `$Hash` dictionary *before* adding the properties calculated in the loop:

```
$Hash = [ordered]@{
    ServerName   = $Server
    "Start Time" = $FirstTimeStamp
    "End Time"   = $LastTimeStamp
}
foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
    $Hash[$Property] = (($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$NumberOfRowsToPick
}
[pscustomobject]$Hash
```

You can also use `$Hash.Insert()` to squeeze new entries in at the top of the dictionary:

```
$Hash = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
    $Hash[$Property] = (($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$NumberOfRowsToPick
}

$hash.Insert(0, 'ServerName', $Server)
$hash.Insert(1, 'Start Time', $FirstTimeStamp)
$hash.Insert(2, 'End Time', $LastTimeStamp)

[pscustomobject]$Hash
```

---

For *existing objects* (ie. if the steps are done by separate scripts), the only way is to create a new object, you could use `Select-Object` for convenience:

```
$csv |Select-Object -Property @('ServerName';'Start Time';'End Time';$Properties)
```

Comment: Just need one info. i don't want to open a new question for this. above i gave only on record for sample. i have multiple records in csv for multiple server. i need to add a new line after each record. as you said i am writing the [pscustomobject]$Hash to csv. so while writing i want to add a new line along with this. how to do this

Comment: @EmptyCoder You could do something like `Get-Content file.csv |ForEach-Object { $_ ; "" } |Set-Content newfile`, although... why?

Comment: because now the data which is getting written is too much mess. so a blank line will separate each record for better visibility

Comment: @EmptyCoder Well, CSV files are not really meant for human consumption - whenever you want to actually inspect the data in a csv with your own eyes, just `Import-Csv` again?

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it is appending newline after each line
I have updated the last part of my question here to show what i am looking for

Comment: @EmptyCoder If you export your data like that, then it's no longer a CSV file and you won't be able to import it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221231/discussion-between-empty-coder-and-mathias-r-jessen).